# Is there a hook that fires before an ajax call?

Tags: ajax, hooks

I'm using the standard admin-ajax.php method of doing ajax. So I have some functions like this:

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_ajax_load_data', 'ajax_load_data' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_ajax_load_data', 'ajax_load_data' );

function ajax_load_data() {
    ...
}
```

I have many ajax functions. Is there a WordPress hook that fires before all of them? My objective is to check for a certain user role so that I can short circuit all ajax calls coming from the front end.

Comment: You can look here: https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.8.2/src/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php You may be able to combine the `admin_init` hook along with the `DOING_AJAX ` define

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you look into this file `wp-admin/admin-ajax.php` where the `wp_ajax_` actions are called, you will find that the `admin_init` action is being called before it.

Here is how to return a different json object based on if the user is admin or not:

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_testing', 'my_ajax' );
add_action( 'admin_init', 'my_ajax_checker', 10, 2);

function my_ajax_checker() {
    if( defined('DOING_AJAX') && DOING_AJAX && current_user_can('manage_options') ) {

        switch($_POST['action']) {
            case 'action1':
            case 'action2':
            case 'action3':
                echo json_encode(array('error' => false));
                die();
        }
    }
}

function my_ajax() {
    echo json_encode(array('error' => true));
    die();
}
```

In this example it checks your actions to see which Ajax action is being called if you are logged in using one of your actions it will always return this json response `'{error:false}'`. It exits immediately and the my_ajax function never gets called. Replace the response with whatever you need it to be.

`DOING_AJAX` isn't always defined when the action `admin_init` is being utilized so make sure to check if its defined first before checking its value.

Comment: .... and that will kill all ajax requests not just his. to make it reasonable you will still need to check for the action being passed.

Comment: @MarkKaplun, lol, yup good catch. Was just throwing out a quick example of how to intercept Ajax calls but I should probably make it less error prone and more to what the OP wanted.

Comment: Thanks, I can work with this and tailor it to suit my objective. Thanks man