# Is it possible to intercept all ajax requests and get the parameters and the returns?

Tags: php, functions, woocommerce-offtopic, ajax, hooks

Is there any hook that always goes through it, where I can see all the requests, and also the returns after the "action" that is executed?

I need to intercept all requests, including requests from WooCommerce, from what I've seen, it looks like it uses another way to do ajax requests.

I need something like this:

Ajax (js object):

```
{
    action: 'getSomePostsHtml',
    param1: 'some param 1',
    param2: 'some param 2'
}
```

Other side by PHP, on my functions.php or other file...:

```
function someAjaxSent() {
    // Some ajax action are sent? pass here...
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($_REQUEST);
    echo '</pre>';

    // show something like this
    // [
    //  action: 'getSomePostsHtml',
    //  param1: 'some param 1',
    //  param2: 'some param 2',
    // ]
}
```

And on return, show what returns after execute action:

```
function someAjaxSentReturnData($dataReturnFromAction) {
    // after execute action, return some data, pass here...
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($dataReturnFromAction);
    echo '</pre>';

    // Array (
    //  [fragment] => Array (
    //      div.something => '<div>Data of posts html...</div>',
    //      div.somehingElse => '<p>Lorem ipsum...</p>'
    //  )
    //  [hash] => ASDF123
    //  [postsFound] => 20
    //  ...
    // )
}
```

My idea is to know and save log of **all** what users are doing in the site/store **via ajax**, for example:

- loading parts of the site via ajax
- filtering products via ajax
- adding to the cart via ajax
- recalculating shipping via ajax
- removing products from cart via ajax
- adding filters and etc...

The part of save this information is already done, I already use in the pages loading with hook `add_action('template_redirect', 'myInterceptFunction');` now I just need to also intercept the ajax requests.

Comment: Keep in mind a lot of newer plugins use the REST API endpoints, not admin AJAX, and that for neither of those is a template loaded, so `template_redirect` wouldn't work

Comment: Yes, I use "template_redirect" only for standard navigation (not for ajax), and seemingly solved for almost every request (except for ajax), now I need some hook that does something similar but in ajax requests.

Comment: One answer available here https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/282651/119672

Comment: @VivekAthalye Doesn't allow you to access or manipulate the response - only completely override it.