# Which allowed API hooks work to add wp_ajax action?

Tags: ajax, hooks

Each time I have to add an ajax function in a WordPress plugin, I lost time to know what is the problem.
So I decided to wrap

```
add_action("wp_ajax{$function_name }", array( $function_class, $function_name ) )
```

with a function which check if there is an error.

This is the actual list of reasons why `wp_ajax` won´t be correctly called :

- The file where there is the php ajax function does not exist
- The class where there is the ajax function is not included before doing

  ```
  add_action("wp_ajax{$function_name }", array( $function_class, $function_name ) )
  ```
- The function or the method inside the class does not exist.
- The ajax function is added in the wrong moment. If you use a hook like this :

  ```
  add_action( "wp_loaded", array( $this, "add_wp_ajax_functions" ) );
  ```

  and add

  ```
  add_action("wp_ajax{$function_name }", array( $function_class, $function_name ) )
  ```

  inside `add_wp_ajax_functions()` that works, but not for all hooks of course.

So, my question is about the last list point. Which hooks are allowed to use the function `add_wp_ajax_functions()`.

For the moment I know that :

***Right hooks***

- wp_loaded
- ?

***Wrong hooks***

- ?

I saw "[If you look into this file wp-admin/admin-ajax.php where the wp_ajax_ actions are called, you will find that the `admin_init` action is being called before it.](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/282645/is-there-a-hook-that-fires-before-an-ajax-call#answer-282651)"

So should have added wp_ajax functions before `admin_init` ?

Comment: have you considered using the newer more modern REST API instead? The REST API gives you error messages in plain english when something goes wrong, and is a lot easier to work with

Comment: This is a question in order to create a function which wrap add_action( "wp_ajax_" ). It will be inside my core code for my plugins. I don´t use REST API for the moment because when I will do it, I need to do a big changement.