# Does a wordpress custom plugin is fired by default on php theme ajax request?

Tags: plugin-development, ajax, hooks

Inside My custom wordpress plugin to translate all posts depending on `get_locale()` I created a php file that's `add_filter()` to each post content element.

Ajax requests are called from `functions.php` and depending php files inside themes folder.

My php code works fine for all page loaded without Ajax.
I want to allowed my plugin to be load before all ajax call/request.
I don't know if I have to hook `wp_ajax_()` inside my php plugin or if an other solution exist or if I've forgotten to apply a wp function when I call ajax so that any plugin can be read automatically.

my typical php ajax :

```
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_filter_date', 'filter_ajax_date');
add_action('wp_ajax_filter_date', 'filter_ajax_date');

function filter_ajax_date(){
    "my wp_query"
    wp_reset_query();
    wp_die();
}
```

When I click on button "date filter" I load posts from other date period using ajax  filter_ajax_date function.

At the end of "my code" I tried to use alone :
`if( wp_doing_ajax() ) {}`
and with 'add_action' from [this code](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/282645/is-there-a-hook-that-fires-before-an-ajax-call/#answers):

```
add_action( 'admin_init', 'my_ajax_checker', 10, 2);

function my_ajax_checker() {
    if( wp_doing_ajax() ) {
         add_action('plugins_loaded', 'atv_convert_multilingual');
    }
}
```

No one works.

My code (my-plugin/includes/multilingual-query.php):

```
function atv_convert_multilingual(){

    if(!is_admin() ){       
        add_filter('the_title','atv_translate_title',10,2);
        add_filter('the_content','atv_translate_content',7);
        add_filter('get_the_excerpt','atv_translate_excerpt',9,2);
        add_filter('get_post_metadata', 'atv_translate_meta_subtitle', 10, 4);
        add_filter('get_post_metadata', 'atv_translate_meta_forwho', 10, 4);
    }

    function atv_translate_lang_post($post_object, $object_id, $whichelement, $metaform = null, $meta_key = null){}

    function atv_translate_title($title, $object_id){
        $whichelement = 'title'; $post_object = $title;
        return  atv_translate_lang_post($post_object, $object_id, $whichelement, null);
    }
}
add_action('plugins_loaded', 'atv_convert_multilingual');
```

For debugging purposes and to avoid my bad practices, here is the function to retrieve the content of the post/postmeta will be modified using add_filter :

```php
function atv_translate_lang_post($post_object, $object_id, $whichelement, $metaform = null, $meta_key = null){

    if ( 'liste_associations' == get_post_type()) {
        $englishforalllang = 'en_GB';               
        if(get_locale() == 'fr_FR'){
            return $post_object;
        }elseif(get_locale() != 'fr_FR' || get_locale() == $englishforalllang ){
            // For POST meta
            if(isset($meta_key) && $metaform == $meta_key){
                $ifposthasmetalang = '/^_[a-z]{2}_[A-Z]{2}$/'; 
                $meta_id = get_post_meta($object_id);
                foreach($meta_id as $metakey => $metaval){
                    if(preg_match($ifposthasmetalang, $metakey)){
                        if($metakey ==  '_'.$englishforalllang || $metakey != '_'.$englishforalllang ){
                            $datalang = get_post_meta( $object_id, $metakey, true );
                            $langcontent = unserialize(base64_decode($datalang));
                                        
                            $post_object = $langcontent[$whichelement];
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            // For POST elements
            if(!isset($meta_key) && !isset($metaform)){
                $ifposthasmetalang = '/^_[a-z]{2}_[A-Z]{2}$/'; 
                global $post;
                if($whichelement == 'title' || $whichelement == 'content'){
                     $meta_id = get_post_meta($object_id);
                }elseif($whichelement == 'excerpt'){
                    $meta_id = get_post_meta($post->ID);
                }
                foreach($meta_id as $metakey => $metaval){
                    if(preg_match($ifposthasmetalang, $metakey)){
                        if($metakey ==  '_'.$englishforalllang || $metakey != '_'.$englishforalllang ){
                            if($whichelement == 'title' || $whichelement == 'content'){
                                $datalang = get_post_meta( $object_id, $metakey, true );
                            }elseif($whichelement == 'excerpt'){
                                $datalang = get_post_meta( $post->ID, $metakey, true );
                            }
                            $langcontent = unserialize(base64_decode($datalang));
    
                            $post_object = $langcontent[$whichelement];
                                            
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            return $post_object;
        }
    }
  }
```

Comment: note that nesting function definitions the way that last code snippet does is very bad practice and may cause fatal errors in the latest versions of PHP and deprecation errors

Comment: also notice that the code you linked to has added that function to multiple hooks, not just `admin_init`, and carries warnings from high rep users in ]the comments that it would break a lot of things. What are you trying to do that originally lead you to this? Also `wp_reset_query` should only be used with `query_posts` which shouldn't be used in 99% of cases.

Comment: So must I repeat each `add_filter()` using conditions of atv_translate_lang_post ? isn't there a best practice that reduces the amount of code required? Because if I decide to remove the nesting of functions as suggested, my code risks becoming extremely long for the use of the same conditions. Can you suggest another way of implementing my code without generating errors?

Comment: I don't know why you would need the conditions like that, `add_action` doesn't need to be at the same level as the function declarations, you can define all functions at the top scope level, nesting is never necessary, and you shouldn't need to duplicate it all

Comment: I see you're using `get_locale` to identify the users locale, but how are you setting it? I also see this: `if ( 'liste_associations' == get_post_type()) {` but this only works if there's a current post set. On an AJAX request there is no context from where the AJAX request was fired from to figure that out either! I'm assuming `$post_object` is a `WP_Post` object? If so you could test the posts type that way via something like `$post_object->post_type` or `$post_object->type` instead of `get_post_type()`? And have you confirmed `get_locale` returns what you expect it to?

Comment: @tom-j-nowell : I'm currently check my ajax function that call posts/event depending on date period (+1week, +2week, +3 and 4 weeks), because I haven't same php code from initial posts call (non ajax). Thanks.  I'm coming back to your advice as soon as I found my mistake .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will never work:

```php
add_action( 'admin_init', 'my_ajax_checker', 10, 2);

function my_ajax_checker() {
    if( wp_doing_ajax() ) {
         add_action('plugins_loaded', 'atv_convert_multilingual');
    }
}
```

This is because by the time `admin_init` runs, `plugins_loaded` has already happened! Making this code would would require the code to travel backwards in time.

Instead it would be much simpler to do this:

```php
add_action('plugins_loaded', 'atv_convert_multilingual');
```

Or this:

```php
if( wp_doing_ajax() ) {
     add_action('plugins_loaded', 'atv_convert_multilingual');
}
```

Take a look at https://www.rarst.net/wordpress/wordpress-core-load/ for more information on the order that hooks fire in WordPress

Comment: Thanks, I already test with your solutions: 
My code works only for non ajax request using `add_action('plugins_loaded', 'atv_convert_multilingual');` . Using this action inside `if( wp_doing_ajax() ) {}` do nothing and ajax request ignore my plugin translation.

Comment: then I don't believe this is actually the problem unless you can demonstrate that this function is not running by putting a `wp_die` in it and not seeing that happen. There is something going on that is not mentioned in your question, code that is missing. `plugins_loaded` _always_ runs, the only reason your action might not run is if it's added after `plugins_loaded` has ran. You should update your question with more information and code about how functions like `atv_translate_lang_post` work, and how you're performing translation as it's difficult if not impossible to debug otherwise

Comment: creating my own template, are there any native wordpress functions that need to be added to `functions.php` so that my theme understands the action of the plugins and more specifically the ajax functions inside `functions.php`?

Comment: I understand, I have added atv_translate_lang_post() function.

Comment: Well, `if( wp_doing_ajax() ) {
     add_action('plugins_loaded', 'atv_convert_multilingual');
}`works fine with simple filter of `$title`on ajax request. I have a problem with `$object_id` and to catch `post_type` as you suggest. yet I have created conditions to retrieve get_locale and post_type from Ajax request but I still stuck to access variable of locale and post_type.

Comment: I resolved my issue by adding a condition inside atv_convert_multilingual() to retrieve locale lang and post_type : `$ajaxorpost_type = isset($activityType) ? $activityType : get_post_type($object_id);` and `$ajaxorpost_locale = isset($definelocale) ? $definelocale : get_locale();` . result = `'liste_associations' == ajaxorpost_type` Also I forgot to add `$object_id`argument to the `get_post_type()`function  inside my initial code . @tom-j-nowell: thanks for your help.